# Como atualizar um DataTable sem dar reload na página?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um `DataTable`(plugin) gerado a partir de um Array que irá montar uma lista de usuário onlines. E monta à paginação.

Porém o **AJAX** que retorna a lista é do tipo **GET** e fica atualizando sempre a página para verificar se algum ID logou e assim atualiza a lista, e para isso eu estou usando o `setTimeOut`.

**Meu problema é:**

Quando estou procurando algum ID usando a paginação, o **GET** é realizado e assim atualiza a página e volta pra primeira pagina.

**Minha dúvida:**

Existe alguma forma de atualizar esse Array conforme é feito o **GET** sem atualizar a página voltando para primeira paginação ?

**Códigos:**

```
 //Função que atualiza a DataTable dos operadores
        function preencheTabelaOperadores() {
            console.log("Preenche Tabela Operadores");
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetQtdeSinaisPorOperador")',
                success: function (data) {

                    var tabelaOperadores = $('#dataTableOperadores').dataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        bProcessing: true,
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                                    { "data": "dsUserName" },
                                    { "data": "nmQtdeSinais" },
                                    { "data": "nmQtdeSinaisPrio1" },
                                    { "data": "nmQtdeSinaisPrio2" },
                                    { "data": "nmQtdeSinaisPrio3" },
                                    {
                                        "data": "nmBloqueado",
                                         "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                             var img

                                             if (data == 3) {
                                                 img = "<center><i class='fa fa-times-circle' style='color:orange; font-size:30px'></i></center>"
                                             } else if (data == 2){
                                                 img = "<center><i class='fa fa-times-circle' style='color:red; font-size:30px'></i></center>"
                                             } else {
                                                 img = "<center><i class='fa fa-check-circle' style='color:green; font-size:30px'></i></center>"
                                             }

                                             return img
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "data": "idUsuario",
                                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                            var btn
                                            btn = "<button type='button' data-backdrop='false' data-item-description="+row.dsUserName+" class='btn bg-red-active deslogar' data-item-id=" + data + "  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCertezaDeslogarUsuario' ><i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i> Deslogar </button>"
                                            return btn
                                        }
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "idUsuario",
                                "render": function (data, type, row1) {
                                    var btn1
                                    btn1 = "<button type='button' data-backdrop='false' data-item-description=" + row1.dsUserName + " class='btn bg-blue-active bloquear' data-item-id=" + data + " data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalCertezaBloquearUsuario' ><i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i> Bloquear Evento</button>"
                                    return btn1
                                }
                            }

                        ],
                        language: {
                            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                            "sInfoPostFix": "",
                            "sInfoThousands": ".",
                            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                            "sSearch": "Pesquisar: ",
                            "oPaginate": {
                                "sNext": "Próximo",
                                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                                "sLast": "Último"
                            },
                            "oAria": {
                                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    data = null;
                }
            });
           setTimeout(preencheTabelaOperadores, 15000);
        }
```